# What are the dimensions of Toyota's U660E Transaxle?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission, engine-swap

I want to do an engine and transaxle swap.

2GR-FE + U660E into a non-Toyota vehicle.

I have the dimensions of the Engine thanks to the internet.

I don't have the dimensions of the transaxle - Length, Width, Height

I have the weight though - Weight: 94.4kg - 208.1lbs

I know Toyota TIS can give me that information but I would rather subscribe when I am ready to do the swap.

I am currently researching the viability of the swap at the moment.

Comment: You should get the transmission so you can do precise measurements as +/- 1/2" will not do  and neither will a wag...

Comment: @I would agree with you

Answer (score 0):

The U660E has many applications including the Camry.

I found the following figures for the application in the Camry:

Length: 570 mm (22.4 in)
Width:  620 mm (24.41 in)
Height: 510 mm (20.07 in)

With this information I have data I can play with to compare with the size of the transaxle in the vehicle.

Data obtained from Toyota!